# Passing a groovy map to a powershell script

Tags: powershell, jenkins-groovy

I have a key-value pair collection in groovy, in a Jenkins pipeline e.g.

```
def procedureParameters = [:]
procedureParameters.put('key','value')
```

I'm trying to pass it to a powershell script -

```
def exitCode = powershell """
    \$parameters = @{
        ${procedureParameters}
    }
"""
```

The above is just an (not working) example, but in the end I want to have a hashtable in powershell that reflect the groovy map that I have.

I have no problems passing a single variable to powershell. But I couldn't find a way to do that with a collection. Is there a good way to do that, before I start serializing my map to string and then deserializing it on the powershell side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, here's a working solution. It still requires to serialize the map into a string. But at least no further processing is required on the powershell side. That's the groovy pipeline code :

```
def powershellInput = "@{"

procedureParameters.each { key, value ->
    powershellInput += "\"$key\"=\"$value\"; "
}

powershellInput += "}"

powershell
"""
    [HashTable]$parameters = ${powershellInput}
"""
```

Another option would be passing it to powershell in an environment variable. But I wasn't able to make it work.